# rails admin join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Hy guys,

Is my first time using rails admin and I have one question how to use join model on rails admin.

I have this models:

```
class Visitor
  attr_accessible :name
end
class Place
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :visits
end
class Visit
  attr_accessible :another_field
  belongs_to :visitor
  belongs_to :place
end
```

and my PlaceConcern is like that:

```
rails_admin do
  edit do
    group :visits do
      field :another_field
      field :visits do
        searchable :name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but that way when I edit/create a tour on my admin panel, when adding a visit, I need to select visitor AND tour. I need a way where the tour will be auto selected (because actually I already have it). How should I configure my concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the inverse_of of your associations. 
You can do it on the associations or on the fields like this:

```
config.model Team do
  field :categories do
    inverse_of :teams
  end
end
```